# Is there any replacement for double colon(::) notation in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, netezza

I am trying to replicate a view from netezza to Hive and getting error while encountering to statement having double colon(::), used for data type casting I think.

Below is the sample statement:

```
CASE WHEN (DB.VW.ABC ISNULL) THEN ''::"NVARCHAR" ELSE DB.VW.ABC END AS ABC_FIXED
```

Comment: Try a Standard SQL type cast: `CAST('' AS NVARCHAR)`. Btw, PostgreSQL also supports this syntax (and Netezza is based on it)

Comment: it worked.. thanks @dnoeth

Comment: @dnoeth post your comment as answer